# Why does Kotlin Nested Lists have this behavior

Tags: kotlin

Take a look at this code example

```
val list = mutableListOf("1", "2", "3")

val listOfLists = mutableListOf(list, list, list)

val firstList = listOfLists[0]     //get reference to *list* variable

firstList[0] = "Hello"            // replace "1" in firstList with "Hello"

print(listOfLists)
```

This is the printed output

```
[[Hello, 2, 3], [Hello, 2, 3], [Hello, 2, 3]]
```

If you notice `listOfLists` variable is never called again in the **but it is not being updated**. And the update is not just at the first position it is updated at all the position.

My intention is just to update the `firstList` variable alone.

Why does this happen and how do I go around it?

Comment: Why would they *not* have that behaviour? You've explicitly built a list containing three references to the *same mutable list*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Java* handles variables as references and therefore *Kotlin* as well. Thus all references change after updating one. You'd have to work with copies of the list to ensure these update independently:

```
val list = listOf("1", "2", "3")
val listOfLists = mutableListOf(
            list.toMutableList(),
            list.toMutableList(),
            list.toMutableList())

val firstList = listOfLists[0]
firstList[0] = "Hello"
print(listOfLists)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's OOP's object behavior man. It affects all the references...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

You are putting three references to the same list in another list. Changing the list via one of those references changes the data to which all references point.

**Solution**

If you don't want that you need to create three independent copies of `list` for example using the [`toMutableList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) extension function:

```
val list = mutableListOf("1", "2", "3")

val listOfLists = mutableListOf(
    list.toMutableList(),
    list.toMutableList(),
    list.toMutableList()
)

listOfLists.first()[0] = "Hello"

print(listOfLists)
```

Output:

> [[Hello, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]